# Can I add with xpath, a new match pattern to an existing list?

Tags: python, xpath

```
def vehicle_callback(self, res):
        self.log(res, INFO) #display URL 
        item = ZOOMItem() #class
        tryy = res.xpath('//section[@class="grid-main"]/h1//span').extract()
```

Can I reuse `tryy` for a new call to `res.xpath` and will Xpath add those new elements to the end of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, if you want to do that you have to get in your list, the balises if you want to access it with xpath.